# In X-men, how is Professor X able to find new mutants?

Tags: marvel, x-men

How is Professor X is able to find all mutants by sitting in his chamber with some mumbo jumbo stuff. How does that stuff work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### That mumbo jumbo is a sophisticated computer-adapted interface designed by Professor X to extend the range of his already prodigious telepathic powers. The device was called Cerebro.

- It was created by Professor X and Moira McTaggart (comic canon, movies may very).
- Its purpose was to allow the Professor to use his telepathic senses, along with the technology he created to detect mutant genetic and psychic profiles from still nascent as well as actively functioning mutants all over the globe.
- Because it was able to detect mutants whose powers had not manifested, it allowed the professor an advantage in finding these mutants before they entered the most dangerous stage of the development, puberty, and allowed him to help them ease into their mutant ability.
- Cerebro and its related technologies could be used by any high order telepath, including Jean Grey and Emma Frost. Later versions could even be used by non-telepaths with varying results.

[image]

*An early image of Cerebro*

From Wikipedia: Cerebro

> In the Marvel Universe, Cerebro (Spanish and Portuguese for "brain") is a device that the X-Men (in particular, their leader, Professor Charles Xavier) use to detect humans, specifically mutants. It was created by Xavier and Magneto, and was later enhanced by Dr. Hank McCoy. The current version of Cerebro is called Cerebra, to be distinguished from the character of the same name. Cerebro first appeared in X-Men (vol 1) #7 (1964).

[image]

*A more modern Cerebro from X-men (2000) showing Professor X, Wolverine, Scott Summers, Storm and Jean Grey*

Comment: As an adjunct to your comment about the movie-canon varying, Professor X states in *X-Men 2* that Magneto helped him build Cerebro. This is implied as being the reason Magneto's helmet blocks Cerebro's signal; having helped design and/ or build Cerebro, Magneto knew how to construct a countermeasure. There's no mention of McTaggart being involved, but also no mention of her *not* being involved, leaving the possibility open that a future film might mention her involvement.