# Can Cerebro measure the strength of a mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Cerebro is the mutant detector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### While [Cerebro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebro), and now Cerebra, lack the ability to act as precisely as a [Dragon Ball Z scouter](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Scouter) by giving a specific rating to a mutant's power level, they have, since 1975, had the ability to gauge a mutant's relative power to determine its potential threat level.

- Cerebro has on various occasions been able to make its users aware if a mutant possessed significantly greater abilities than the average mutant.

[image]

[image]

- In **[Giant-Size_X-Men #1 (1975)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant-Size_X-Men)**, Cerebro reveals the existence of a mutant whose power level has never been seen before, the living island **[Krakoa](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Krakoa_(Earth-616))**.
- Since Xavier says Krakoa defies classification, Cerebro must give some simplified scale by which a mutant's abilities can be rated.

[image]

> Krakoa was originally a very small island in the Pacific Ocean that was located close to where some nuclear bombing tests were done. The radiation somehow turned the island's ecosystem into a hive-mind entity.

**See Also: [In X-men, how is Professor X able to find new mutants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/42874/2765)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent and informative answer!